# sending mail in loop using cakephp email component ,appends content to next mail content

Tags: email, components, cakephp-1.3

CAKEPHP CONTROLLER CODE :

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++) {   
   $to = 'pretesting@gmail.com';

   $subject = 'Cloud Network Invitation';

   $template = "email/join";

   $activation_code = md5(uniqid($to, true));

   $this->Email->reset();

   $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';

   $this->Email->to = $to;

   $this->Email->from = 'pretesting2@gmail.com';

   $this->Email->subject = $subject;

   $this->Email->template = $template;

   $this->set(compact('activation_code','to'));     

   $this->Email->send();

}
```

For the first time , i get this in my  'pretesting2@gmail.com' inbox

> Hi, pretesting2@gmail.com

For the 2nd time , i get this in my  'pretesting2@gmail.com' inbox

```
Hi, pretesting2@gmail.com
Hi, pretesting2@gmail.com
```

Dont able to understand , why 1st mail content is appended to 2nd mail contents..

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use $this->Email->reset() within your loop. You can read more here, http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Email.html

If your still having trouble, try to debug with $this->Email->delivery = 'debug';

Comment: Thanks for your reply, already using $this->Email->reset(); and $this->Email->delivery = 'debug'; also gone through your link....

Comment: if you could include more information like the full function and email template, it would be easier to suggestion solutions